# Multiple entries in apache access log

Tags: apache-2.4, gcp, moodle

In the apache access log for bitnami moodle on GCP, there are multiple entries (added every second!!) as given below. This is leading to a very high egress traffic. I would appreciate any pointers to resolve this issue.

```
52.70.240.171 - - [17/Mar/2024:17:34:25 +0530] "GET /lib/requirejs.php/1684130153/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.imageUrl(%22t/expanded%22)+%22/%22/%22 HTTP/1.1" 200 315815

52.70.240.171 - - [17/Mar/2024:17:34:26 +0530] "GET /lib/requirejs.php/1684130153/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.imageUrl(%22t/expanded%22)+%22/%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.imageUrl(%22t/expanded%22)+%22/%22/ HTTP/1.1" 200 315815

23.22.35.162 - - [17/Mar/2024:17:34:26 +0530] "GET /lib/requirejs.php/1684130153/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+b.params.cookiePolicyUrl+%22/%22%22+h.link+%22/%22%22+b.imageUrl(%22t/collapsed%22)+%22/%22/%22 HTTP/1.1" 200 315815
```

I'm not sure what is causing this. Is there a way to identify the root of this problem? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse lookup of the IP's shows hostnames like for example:

`dig -x 52.70.240.171` --> `52-70-240-171.crawl.amazonbot.amazon.`

[Amazon crawlbot](https://developer.amazon.com/amazonbot) is well-behaved and will honour a [`robots.txt`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt) exclusion directive if you have a need to block access completely or partially.

Additionally: Amazonbot supports the link-level `rel=nofollow` directive. Include these in your HTML to keep Amazonbot for following and not crawling a particular link from your website.

Often logging the User-Agent string in your web server logs helps identifying bots and crawlers even more quickly.

Comment: There is no robots.txt file in the root directory of the site so that should "tells all robots to stay out of a website" (as per wiki page). Also, I would like to add that the incoming traffic is negligible but the egress is very high. So, I guess, there is something within the virtual machine that's adding these logs. Is there something else that I can try to fix this? Many thanks!

Comment: Also, things were fine about a month ago. Then something happened leading to these logs. Not sure what is causing this.

Comment: Your interpretation of the Wikipedia article and *”If this file (`robots.txt`) does **not** exist, web robots assume that the website **owner does not wish to place any limitations** on crawling the entire site.”* (emphasis mine) is incorrect, the absence of a robots.txt allow crawlers to do as they please. - in general for web servers you expect ingress to be negligible compared to egress , the request `get page` or other resources is tiny compared to a server response containing your HTML , content or images etc.